# Why is there a parse error in this Haskell 'else if' statement?

Tags: parsing, haskell, sudoku

I am looking for a hint or explanation as to why this chunk of code keeps getting a parse error on the first else if statement in the block. It says it may be a problem with indentation or parenthesis but I cant seem to find them. So I was looking for another set of experienced eyes to set me on the right course. I feel like there is something very small I am overlooking, but I just cant seem to find it. This is for a sudoku solver(Ill admit the whole sudoku solver is a class assignment. This is my first time posting so Im not 100% certain if this is an acceptable question, please let me know if it is not).

This function is to take a sudoku game board (Which is basically a list of lists) and two ints which are the coordinates for the 3x3 section of the board you are looking at and then return the sequence of numbers from that 3x3 section of board.

I know this isnt the haskelian way to solve this problem (I sort of brute forced it in the end), Im really only been learning Haskell for a few weeks, but I wanted to figure out why the else if keeps popping up as an error.

```
getBox :: Board -> Int -> Int -> Sequence
getBox b x y = do
  let i = x
  let j = y


  let x0 = b!!0
  let x1 = b!!1
  let x2 = b!!2
  let x3 = b!!3
  let x4 = b!!4
  let x5 = b!!5
  let x6 = b!!6
  let x7 = b!!7
  let x8 = b!!8

  if (i==0 && j==0)
      then let z = [x0!!0, x0!1, x0!!2, x1!!0 x1!!1, x1!!2, x2!!0, x2!!1, x2!!2]
  else if (i==0 && j==1)
      then let z = [x0!!3, x0!4, x0!!5, x1!!3 x1!!4, x1!!5, x2!!3, x2!!4, x2!!5]
  else if (i==0 && j==2)
      then let z = [x0!!6, x0!7, x0!!8, x1!!6 x1!!7, x1!!8, x2!!6, x2!!7, x2!!8]
  else if (i==1 && j==0)
      then let z = [x3!!0, x3!!1, x3!!2, x4!!0, x4!!1, x4!!2, x5!!0, x5!!1, x5!!2]
  else if (i==1 && j==1)
      then let z = [x3!!3, x3!!4, x3!!5, x4!!3, x4!!4, x4!!5, x5!!3, x5!!4, x5!!5]
  else if (i==1 && j==2)
      then let z = [x3!!6, x3!!7, x3!!8, x4!!6, x4!!7, x4!!8, x5!!6, x5!!7, x5!!8]
  else if (i==2 && j==0)
      then let z = [x6!!0, x6!!1, x6!!2, x7!!0, x7!!1, x7!!2, x8!!0, x8!!1, x8!!2]
  else if (i==2 && j==1)
      then let z = [x6!!3, x6!!4, x6!!5, x7!!3, x7!!4, x7!!5, x8!!3, x8!!4, x8!!5]
  else let z = [x6!!6, x6!!7, x6!!8, x7!!6, x7!!7, x7!!8, x8!!6, x8!!7, x8!!8]
```

Comment: Your compiler should tell you what's wrong. In particular your indentations are off!

Comment: This is a terrible way to approach this problem.  You should try to learn the basic syntactical approaches that haskell has rather than brute forcing it this way.

Comment: also please share a complete example (with the main function) so that someone can test it out

Comment: `let` must be followed by some code that uses the defined variable, otherwise it's completely useless. All your `let`s aren't followed by anything.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Well, the first 11 are "fine" because they're in a do block (although obviously very messy either way).

Comment: Holy heck, there's a lot of oddities in this one snippet. Can I recommend that once you get it doing what you want you take it over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @amalloy yes, you're right. I only meant the ones inside the `if`s.

Comment: Please do not use `do`, unless you understand the implications. It usually results in people trying to write imperative-style in Haskell.

Comment: You could replace the 9 _let_ lines for the initialization of variables x0 to x8 by some pattern matching: `let [x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8] = board  in  (some expression using the xi variables)` as it seems your Board data type is a list.

Comment: You could define a tiny list sectioning function like this : `let sp ln idx ls = (take ln . drop idx) ls` and then you can replace this: `[x3!!6, x3!!7, x3!!8, x4!!6, x4!!7, x4!!8, x5!!6, x5!!7, x5!!8]` by that: `(sp 3 6 x3) ++ (sp 3 6 x4) ++ (sp 3 6 x5)` and on top of that you can get rid of the `let z` at the left of those code lines.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete `let z =` everywhere it appears, and you'll be on your way to your next error.

Answer (score 0):

A `let` expression has a binding and a body.  A prototypical `let` expression is:

```
let x = 2 in x + x
    ^^^^^    ^^^^^
   binding    body
```

Which just means *substitute `2` for `x`* in the body. That's all `let` ever means (that is, you could always get rid of the `let` manually by substituting).  It is a bit obscured by the allowed syntax for `let` within a `do` block, which may give the impression that it is like a mutable variable in an imperative language, but it is not.

```
do 
    let i = x
    let j = y
    pure (i + j)
```

Means

```
let i = x in 
  let j = y in 
    pure (i + j)
```

That is, the body of the let is the remainder of the `do` block.

Any variable can be traced back to a single unique definition or function parameter.  A variable can't be defined by multiple different `let` statements dynamically, as you are trying to do.  You need to define `z` only once.  In your case, this can be done with *guards*, which is a way to make conditional definitions.

```
let z
    | i == 0 && j == 0 = [x0!!0, x0!!1, -- oh my god I am not typing this
    | i == 0 && j == 1 = [x0!!3, x0!!4, -- more?
    | ...
```

You could have also done it without guards, you just need to move your chain of `if`s inside the `let`:

```
let z = if i == 0 && j == 0 then [...]
        else if i == 0 && j == 1 then [...]
        ...
```

I hope this helps.  May the pains of your brute-force solutions be amortized.